# Show the selected option before a form was submitted

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, html-select

This is what I have in my view:

```
<%= form_tag(request.url, :method => 'get') do %>
  <%= select_tag(:filter, options_for_select([['all', 'all'], ['Active & Planned', 'active_planned'], ['Archived', 'archived']])) %>
<% end %>
```

I can access the selected "filter" using `params[:filter]`. How can I show the one that was selected when the form was submitted? Right now it always goes back to the first option, `all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as below

```
  <%= select_tag(:filter, options_for_select([['all', 'all'], ['Active & Planned', 'active_planned'], ['Archived', 'archived']], params[:filter])) %>
```

This will select the option value which is equal to params[:filter]